# openam installation error: Rebuilding OpenDJ indexes...Failed 1

Tags: openam

I'm trying to install openam 10 using a TomcatV6 and a JVM6. When the opensso configuration wizard is show, I select the "New Configuration" option. Everything seems to work fine, but when the wizard starts with the last step of the installation I get the next error message: **"Rebuilding OpenDJ indexes...Failed 1"**

As result the installation is not complete.

Any help?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Well, I finally resolve the problem reinstalling the whole Tomcat Server. I tried to delete work and temp folders but it didn't work. The solution was deleting the tomcat folder and reinstalling it.